# Restore form values on form submission cancel

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, formik

I am working on formik in reacts for forms. I have submit button which is working fine. When I click submit, a modal will be shown with two buttons, "Continue eiting"(navigates back to form) and "Submit"(submits data to db and goes back to home).
But when I click "Continue editing", what ever the values I filled in are clearing and it is going back to previous state.

Can anyone suggest how to keep those values on form , after I go click "continue editing"?

When I click submit, sending value as: true

```
const setShowPreCampaignModal = (value) => () => {
setModalSettings(prevState => {
  return {
    ...prevState,
    showPreSubmitModal: value,
  }
});
```

}

//This is the modal it is showing up after clicking submit

```
const renderPreCampaignSubmitModal = () => {
    let firstText = 'Once you submit the campaign, you won't be able to edit .'
    let secondText = 'If you want to keep editing the page, return to the campaign where you can change the details and save the campaign.'

    if (modalSettings.showPreSubmitModal) {
      return (
        <ModalConstructor
          headerInnerHtml="Ready to submit?"
          bodyInnerHtml={renderModalBody({ firstText, secondText })}
          dialogClasses="modal__container"
          footerInnreHtml={renderModalButtons({
            transparentBtnTxt: "Continue Editing",
            blueBtnTxt: "Submit",
            onTransparentClick: setShowPreCampaignModal(false),
            onBlueClick: submitCampaignNewUsingLocalFetch
          })}
          headerClasses="modal__header"
        />
      )
    }
  }
```

Comment: Are these separate screens that you're actually navigating to?  Or is the modal simply another component that's hidden until submission?  A little code would make it easier to help

Comment: Can you please share the code or a sandbox

Comment: @DannyBuonocore modal is another component just hidden until I click submit

Comment: Do you have code for this?

Comment: @DannyBuonocore added code associated with that